# how do you catch exception with google cloud storage api

Tags: google-cloud-storage, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I can't seem to catch this exception, except through the catch-all

```
from google.cloud import storage, exceptions

def gsutil_ls(bucket_name, filter=None, project_id=None):
  try:
    client = storage.Client( project=project_id )
    bucket_path = "gs://{}/".format(bucket_name)
    bucket, err = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    files = ["{}{}".format(bucket_path,f.name) for f in bucket.list_blobs() ]
    if filter:
      files = [f for f in files if filter in f]
    # print(files)
    return files
  except exceptions.NotFound:
    raise ValueError("ERROR: GCS bucket not found, path={}".format(bucket_path))
  except Exception as e:
    print( e)



gsutil_ls("my-bucket", project_id="my-project")
```

returns:

`400 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-bucket?projection=noAcl: Invalid bucket name: 'my-bucket'`

see: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.get_bucket

Comment: I believe you're landing in the last `except` clause -- what if you print `type(e)` as well?

Comment: dooh! `<class 'google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden'>`

Answer (score 2):

In this case, for:

`400 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-bucket?projection=noAcl: Invalid bucket name: 'my-bucket'`

use `exceptions.Forbidden`

```
  try:
     [...]
  except exceptions.Forbidden:
    raise ValueError("ERROR: GCS bucket not found, path={}".format(bucket_path))
```